# Spring WS & Spring -integration : org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted

Tags: web-services, spring-ws, spring-integration

I am trying to call a web service that uses Axis 2 and SOAP 1.2 using Spring Integration and Spring-ws. I am getting the following error

14:53:50,646 DEBUG SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway:67 - org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway#102be12 received message: [Payload=                        BILUXUSR         iBfgVOlz4JLeZo6sAL70fQ==         2012-07-27T12:12:30.265Z                        http://20.15.81.224:9080/commfw_billing_reg412                                             CSC           UX                             613E8001881C4FFC90CB8E6D46C22362                 http://www.csc.com/standards/PC_Surety/AcordCsc1/AccountInquire/AccountInformation     uuid:89f7261c-16d0-4983-9dce-e411495ad5b7     http://20.15.81.224:9080/commfw_billing_reg412/services2/AccountInquire                  319DA5F3-A73C-45DE-B54C537BF852653E       12/09/2012       USD                MEW-BILL1                 ][Headers={timestamp=1343813030646, id=dc39d221-f257-452b-9f26-6ea1b14489a6, ws_soapAction=http://www.csc.com/standards/PC_Surety/AcordCsc1/AccountInquire/AccountInformation}]
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway#102be12]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:118)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at com.csc.billingux.WebServiceClient.sendRequesttoService(WebServiceClient.java:40)
    at com.csc.billingux.rest.AccountServiceAdapter.accountService(AccountServiceAdapter.java:47)
    at com.csc.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.NodeImpl.insertBefore(NodeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.xml.utils.DOMBuilder.append(DOMBuilder.java:179)
    at org.apache.xml.utils.DOMBuilder.startElement(DOMBuilder.java:326)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1072)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:484)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport.transform(TransformerObjectSupport.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway$SimpleRequestMessageCallback.doWithMessageInternal(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway$RequestMessageCallback.doWithMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:215)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:571)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    ... 37 more

```
Can anyone is having a clue as  i am quite new to web services development.
```

Thanks

Comment: @Gary Russell Please look into this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like malformed XML; suggest you google "hierarchy_request_err java"; there are lots of results that might help you. If you can't figure it out, post the XML here and maybe someone can help.